# Integrate copyright label in qgis2web export?

Tags: qgis, qgis2web

I want to integrate an always visible link into a qgis2web leaflet map.
My ideas / I tried this:

- view... decorations... copyright label = not show there
- change the qgis project title, also with html = not the best solution, false position
- try to change the index html = no success

**Is it possible to take the copyright label within qgis/decoration?**
It would be good, because I can use html for this field and it is always present after every map-export.

I use QGIS 2.18.12 (windows 10)

Answer (score 3):

No, that's not implemented. What is brought through to the export is *layer* attributions (I think). Try setting an attribution on one of your layers, and see whether that works. In the meantime, I'll try to add in support for the project attribution, as you suggest.

EDIT:
You can add a layer attribution by following these steps:

- Right click on the layer in the `Layers` pane.
- Select `Properties...`.
- Select `QGIS Server` towards the bottom left of the popup window.
- Go to `Attribution`
- What you enter in the `Title` field will appear in the bottom right corner of the leaflet map.
- And it will link to the URL you enter in the `Url` field. Make sure to include `https://` when linking to a website.